# How to find changes overtime in database entries?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database that is generated from another system and imported to Google Sheets.

It includes items and fields with their values overtime (including timestamps). I want to create a report that will output the date when a field changed for each individual item, as well as the old and new value.

I was able to do this with a query function where I am using 'offset' to compare rows and then a combination of functions to output the changes:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lgZqGzfo0lULLSeJHWSuGUf7jGDmE3rFKSi8sZ1ctPg/edit#gid=917945249

The problem is that using 'offset' I am mixing items (as you can see in the red commentary). Those are not changes in values, but rather information about a new item that is compared to the information of a different item (in the previous row)

ASK: how can I ensure that 'offset' is applied based on the item? so it doesn't compare values for different items

Update: desired output is provided in the "changes output" tab in the spreadsheet (excluding column g)

Comment: pls provide full example of desired result in your sheet

Comment: @player0 the output was provided in the "changes output" tab in the spreadsheet (excluding the commentary in column G)